# c# using tesseract language

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use downloaded custom language for the google's Tesseract OCR engine, it has the following files but no traineddata file, please see my code below which gives me an error only when I try to use the new language, can someone help.

files:
cp27.DangAmbigs
cp27.freq-dawg
cp27.inttemp
cp27.normproto
cp27.pffmtablecp
cp27.unicharset
cp27.user-words
cp27.word-dawg

Download Link: http://www.sendspace.com/file/gd7j4i
error message: Failed to initialise tesseract engine

```
Pix test = PixConverter.ToPix(image);

try
{
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata", @"cp27", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", charset);

        using (var page = engine.Process(test))
        {
            return(page.GetText());
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```

Comment: Why not post the error?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error message.

error message: Failed to initialise tesseract engine.

Comment: That's the entire stack trace?

Comment: that's the error message what i get, if I change the cp27 to eng, it all works but I want to use the new language

Comment: I have uploaded the file, if anyone could please have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run Tesseract `combine_tessdata` command to combine your files into a `cp27.traineddata` file.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Comment: thanks for that info, I have combined the files into cp27.traineddata now it gives another error message.

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Tesseract.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: It might be that the files were not properly generated. Were all the steps strictly followed?

Comment: I've downloaded tesseract-ocr-3.02-win32-portable.zip, then I copyed all 8 files into tessdata folder and from cmd I entered  combine_tessdata tessdata\cp27. which it created a file called  cp27.traineddata

Comment: here's the output from cmd. Combining tessdata files, TessdataManager combined tesseract data files., Offset for type 0 is -1, Offset for type 1 is 140, Offset for type 2 is -1, Offset for type 3 is 353, Offset for type 4 is 359683, Offset for type 5 is 359894, Offset for type 6 is -1, Offset for type 7 is 406758, Offset for type 8 is -1, Offset for type 9 is 406770, Offset for type 10 is -1, Offset for type 11 is -1, Offset for type 12 is -1, Offset for type 13 is -1, Offset for type 14 is -1, Offset for type 15 is -1, Offset for type 16 is -1

Comment: I reread your original post and realize that your lang data files are of Tesseract 2.0x, not 3.0x, version. As such, you will need the .NET wrapper for Tesseract 2.0x, [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/). .trainnedata is for Tesseract 3.0x version.

Comment: Also, `cp27.pffmtablecp` should be renamed as `cp27.pffmtable`.

Comment: thank you for all your help and efforts, I've got it working using tessnet2.

Answer (score 0):

for create lang.traineddata use [combine_tessdata](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) command in current directory.

follow exception occur when there is **one instance of tesseract** and you want call tesseract as **service**(more than one request at a time) or as **parallel**. in your wrapper when use:

```
tesseract::TessBaseApi *api
```

you should allocate memory (new) to api, so use:

```
api new tesseract::TessBaseApi()
```

i tested it and work correctly.

> System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Tesseract.dll Additional
>   information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is
>   often an indication that other memory is corrupt."